# Why are these loops incrementing strangely?

Tags: c, loops, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){

        int rows, col, i, j;
        char **mazeArrP;

        scanf("%d %d", &rows, &col);

        mazeArrP = (char **) malloc(rows*sizeof(char));

        for(i = 0; i<rows; i++){

            printf("i = %d\n", i);
            mazeArrP[i] = (char *) malloc(col*sizeof(char));

            for(j = 0; j<col; j++){

                printf("j = %d\n", j);
                scanf("%c", &mazeArrP[i][j]);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I used the print to identify where in the loop I currently am. I'm trying to create a simple 2D array of characters but my loops are acting oddly. This is the first time I've tried using a double pointer to create a 2D array so any help in that area is greatly appreciated as well. Its seems to be 0,0 and going to 0,1 then asking for a scan, then skipping to i=1 j =0, so on and so forth. Am i missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mazeArrP = (char **) malloc(rows*sizeof(char));
```

is wrong. Change to

```
mazeArrP = malloc(rows * sizeof(*mazeArrP));
```

Also, the line

```
mazeArrP[i] = (char *) malloc(col*sizeof(char));
```

can be written as

```
mazeArrP[i] = malloc(col);
```

`sizeof(char)` is 1 so it is redundant.

Comment: don't cast `malloc` output

Comment: @P0W yeah, i will mention that. Thanks.

Comment: @Smac89 `sizeof(*mazeArrP)` is better because it will be correct even if you change the type of `mazeArrP`

Comment: @haccks [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) You will get to know.

Comment: Thank you for the malloc info!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `malloc` issue,

Your loop is behaving *"strangely"* because the trailing newline from previous `scanf` is taken as new input.

So use:

```
int c;
while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF) ; //to remove newlines from previous scanf
```

after `scanf`

Comment: Just Changing `scanf("%c", &mazeArrP[i][j]);` to `scanf(" %c", &mazeArrP[i][j]);` will also work. Because adding `space` before `%c` acts as `fflush();`

Comment: I originally didn't have any prints or new lines but added them because the loop would only scan 4 characters opposed to 6. When I removed the print commands all together it still is only scanning 4 characters and incrementing strangely.

Comment: @VedantTerkar; This is one of favorite line of P0W. He used it many times here. :)

Comment: @RJones Glad that my comment was useful for you.

Comment: @VedantTerkar Thank you to both you and P0W!